# How to debug code in visual studio 2005/2010 which is hosted to IIS of some other system(windows xp) which is in LAN?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, visual-studio-debugging

I deployed published code of my website which is made in visual studio 2005 to my system's IIS.
Website is working fine.

Same code is deployed to QC environment for testing, but code is not working well there. 
At QC environment we are getting some error :
"Unable to get records. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I am not getting that error to my local code.

Can you please suggest how can i debug the code with my local Visual Studio, code is deployed to QC's system ?

Comment: Years ago I did some remote debugging with VS 2005, but it's been a long time.  I do remember that it tended to tie up all the resources on the remote machine.  As a simpler alternative, if you can narrow down where the error is, put some logging in that area of the code and deploy it to the QC environment to see what's actually going on.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can't debug code of system on LAN . You need to install Visual studio on the QC System and then attach to the `w3wp.exe` process for relevant application pool, then send the request and see whats going on there.